# WordPress: How can I create an "all posts" page?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Seems like this should be simple. I'm using Starkers to create my theme. I have a static home page. My "home.php" template looks like this:

```
<?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array( 'parts/shared/html-header') ); ?>
    [ static content here... ]

<?php 
    $args= array('posts_per_page' => 5);
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args); 
?>
<?php if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    [dynamic output here... ]
<?php endwhile; // end of one post ?>
<?php endif; //end of loop ?>

<?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array('parts/shared/html-footer') ); ?>
```

This works fine. I also have a template called "episodes" (this theme is for a podcast site), which looks like this:

```
<?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array( 'parts/shared/html-header') ); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    [dynamic output here... ]
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array('parts/shared/html-footer') ); ?>
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. In each of the page's edit panels, I've set the appropriate template from the dropdown list. Also in settings > reading I have set "front page displays" to "a static page" and also set front page to "home" and posts page to "episodes"

However, the episodes page displays the home page template.

I'm assuming there's something wrong with the episodes.php template, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it could be. It's driving me bonkers!

Thanks in advance for any help or insight.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Starkers but it seems to me that you are using a 'protected' page template `home.php`.
It should work if you changed the names to `page-home.php` and `page-episodes.php`.

Another solution would be to use the wordpress page template as mentioned in [wp template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), then you would have to change

`episodes.php` → `home.php`

and

`home.php` → `front-page.php`